# Possible to control &shy; appearance?

Tags: html, css, word-break, soft-hyphen, css-hyphens

I've discovered that there are different ways the soft hyphen can break up a word, depending on the width of the word wrapper.

The [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/3q7oj14a/1/) shows this clearly.

The first two words (in the example) look like I expect them to, but the last two are a mystery to me. **Can someone tell me why `&shy;` is displayed with the dash in the end of the word?**

Edit: As Oriol points out, different browsers and environments produce different views. Here is a picture of what I see:

[image]

Comment: My Firefox and Chromium do 2 cases differently. Testing other versions or browsers would produce even more variability for sure. I have no idea about what you see and what you want.

Comment: @Oriol: Added a picture.

Comment: Yes please. Some input on what can be done, or why this is happening would be super.

Comment: Funnily enough, this works perfectly fine in IE11. So it could just be a Chrome bug.